# Error starting service?

Tags: boot, 16.04, xubuntu, system, apparmor

Can someone assist with debugging and/or resolving this "Active: failed" warning? I'm a little new to Ubuntu, not sure how to handle this.

```
$ systemctl status apparmor.service
● apparmor.service - LSB: AppArmor initialization
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apparmor; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-08-18 ; 24s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4641 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apparmor start (code=exited, status=123)

apparmor[4641]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.dnsmasq
apparmor[4641]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.mdnsd
apparmor[4641]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
apparmor[4641]: profile has merged rule with conflicting x modifiers
apparmor[4641]: ERROR processing regexs for profile /usr/lib/firefox/firefox{,*[^s][^h]}, failed to load
apparmor[4641]:    ...fail!
systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=123
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


$ systemctl restart apparmor.service
Job for apparmor.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apparmor.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


$ apt-cache policy apparmor-*

apparmor:
  Installed: 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2

apparmor-utils:
  Installed: 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.2
```